# How to place custom shape in the appbar

Tags: flutter, dart

- I have created custom shape in flutter. I am new to flutter to bare with silly doubt.
- I am trying to place the shape in the appbar as shown in the below image. I think I am messing up in calling the method for the shapes.
- I want the shapes to be behind the icons so it gives a look like in the above image.
- For now I am just able to do it after the appbar section.
- `Code`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../model/Events.dart';
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Events> _allEvents = Events.allEvents();

  HomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: new Text(
            "YWCA of Bombay",
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'LilyScriptOne',
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.black87),
          ),

          // Burgermenu Starts
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {/* Write listener code here */},
            child: Icon(
              Icons.menu, // add custom icons also
            ),
          ),
          // Burgermenu Ends

          // Events & Search bar Starts
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(80),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('Events',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                new TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Search by venue",
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.mic,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // Cards
        ),
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: OpenPainter(),
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
class OpenPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint1 = Paint()
      ..color = Color(0xff49DEE8).withOpacity(0.5)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    //a circle
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(20, 50), 100, paint1);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(120, -10), 100, paint1);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

- What I want it like

[image]

- What is the result as of now for the above code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is make the AppBar color transparent. A Scaffold also has a property called [`extendBodyBehindAppBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBodyBehindAppBar.html).

You can use it to show the body behind the AppBar.